# Microsoft Visual Studio showing error "Failed to create component 'AxHost'" while importing Windows Media Player

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2022

I'm creating a Windows Forms App on Visual Studio 2022. When I import the Windows Media Player to my project it is showing me this error.

[image: This is the error I'm getting]

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: Tried with the same setup (VS 2022, .NET Framework project) and it worked as expected.

Comment: Not supported in a .NETCore project, ensure the project template you start with has ".NET Framework" in its name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Windows Media Player in VS, you can refer to this page.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/using-the-windows-media-player-control-with-microsoft-visual-studio

Following these steps we can import Windows Media Player successfully.
[image]
[image]

Comment: This no longer works in VS2022. Any other solution?